# Prove limit superior of a sequence is greater than or equal to limit superior of the Cesàro mean of that sequence

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is that:

> Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence, and $x^* =\limsup(x_n)$.
>   Prove 
>   $$\lim\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x_n}{n}\le x^*.$$

I want to prove it by contradiction.

I start with assume that $\lim\sum_{i=0}^n (x_n)/n> x^*$, then I know $\exists N \in \mathbb N$ (natural number) such that $x_n < \lim \sum_{i=0}^n (x_n)/n$ for all $n \ge N$. "

Then I do not know how to find a contradiction, could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you missing a $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Your proof cannot work, because if $x_n$ is decreasing you always have $(\sum_{i=0}^n x_n)/n > x^*$...

Comment: @JohnMa        Yes, thank you very much

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini   or should i start from the definition of limit superior?

Comment: It is not even clear to me that $\lim\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{x_n}n$ exists. Do you mean  $\limsup\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{x_n}n$?